# Copying absolute filepath of selected file in Netrw

Tags: netrw, filesystem

Is it possible to copy the absolute filepath of the file under the cursor in Netrw?

Answer (score 3):

You can select the file under cursor through visual block mode, like `Ctrl+V`, then press `$` and then a `j` and then a `y`.

Now, in command line mode,
Type

```
:echo @%.@"
```

This will show the full path of the file under cursor.

You can also map it to a key,
Like

```
:map \f ^<C-V>$jy:echo @%.@"<CR>
```

Now, you can press `\f` while the cursor is on a file and it will print it's full path in command line.

Comment: What if I am in TreeListing mode?

Comment: Is it not working there?

Comment: that does not seem to work reliably.

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem to be possible out of the box. Here is a small patch, that should do what you want:

```
diff --git a/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim b/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim
index de85844..c18d85d 100644
--- a/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim
+++ b/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim
@@ -6052,6 +6052,7 @@ fun! s:NetrwMaps(islocal)
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> v       :call <SID>NetrwSplit(5)<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> x       :<c-u>call netrw#BrowseX(<SID>NetrwBrowseChgDir(1,<SID>NetrwGetWord(),0),0)"<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> X       :<c-u>call <SID>NetrwLocalExecute(expand("<cword>"))"<cr>
+   nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> _        :call setreg(v:register, get(b:, 'current_dir', getcwd()). '/'. <SID>NetrwGetWord())<cr>
"   " local insert-mode maps
"   inoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> a      <c-o>:call <SID>NetrwHide(1)<cr>
"   inoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> c      <c-o>:exe "NetrwKeepj lcd ".fnameescape(b:netrw_curdir)<cr>
```

Using this, you can copy a file path using the <kbd>_</kbd> key

*Update (2021)*:
With netrw v170 you can also do this:

```
:echo getcwd() .. (&shellslash ? '/' : '\') .. netrw#Call("NetrwGetWord")
```

You can of course map it to e.g. return the result directly into a register.

Comment: I think it's possible now (`echo netrw#Call("NetrwGetWord")`), you may want to update the answer?

Comment: @user202729  With what netrw version does that work?

Comment: (I mean that one just echo the selected file, you need extra logic to copy it) but I'm using v170.

Comment: Well, it's just slightly more comfortable. You still need to prefix it with the current directory. But I have just added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another option is modifying the `netrw.vim` script found in `/usr/share/vim/vim<your version here>/autoload/` as follows:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> P     : call NetrwGetPath()

function! NetrwGetPath()

    let dirname = s:NetrwTreeDir(0)                                                                  
    let filename = s:NetrwGetWord()       

    " this global variable will store the path that you want copied from netrw                 
    let g:netrwtemppath = dirname."/".filename

endfunction
```

where P can be substituted for any key you want to remap for this. Then all you need to do to paste into a file is:

```
:put =netrwtemppath
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Why modify the shipped `netrw.vim` instead of extending it through a separate file? One issue with overwriting it is that updating the Vim package will undo your modifications...

Comment: I agree, that's a definite flaw of my answer. I just didn't understand the other answer and wanted to try something simple that I knew how it worked. My function relies only on two built in functions. I suppose I could have written all that in a separate file and then just made the two built in functions accessible to my script, but that's still a modification of the shipped netrw.vim. Would love any suggestions for making my function in a separate script without modifying netrw.vim.